# Element tag inside a xsl variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XSLT like this

```
<xsl:variable name="test">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(test_id) !=''">
            <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length(test_id)" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="($length &lt; 12)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="test_id" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Error> test_id: <xsl:value-of select="$invalid" /> test_id is greater than 11 characters</Error>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
```

The issue is that in the output XML if the test_id is more than 11 chars the output i get is

```
test_id: <data> test_id is greater than 11 chars
```

what I want is

```
<Error> test_id: <data> test_id is greater than 11 chars </Error>
```

If this section of the code is outside the xsl:variable it works, how to get this work inside a variable as this section of the code is used in multiple places.

Comment: Your current and expect result are not really readable, I guess you are struggling with the different of `xsl:copy-of select="$test"` versus `xsl:value-of select="$test"`, only `copy-of` will copy nodes in node-set and result tree fragments, `value-of` creates a text node with the string value of the node or result tree fragment selected.

Comment: Can you show us how $invalid is initialized?  If it's a parameter, it is possible the variable is being initialized before the parameter.  In which case, you'll get an empty string in the variable.  In the debugger ensure $invalid has the value you want before entering the test variable.  Then let us know.

Comment: BTW:  If that's the case, use the invaild parameter before using in test variable.  For example, right after your param's you could try <xsl:variable name="a" select="$invalid"/>

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried with xsl:copy-of and it still did not work. I still do not see the <Error> element in the output.

Comment: @Bluewood66 i get the value of the parameter correctly. The issue is that I do not see <Error> element in the output

Comment: Post a minimal but complete XSLT sample, XML input samples, result sample and expected result sample, together with information of the used XSLT processor to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: All - Please ignore my question. I had couple of variables which calls the final variable section. I have to use xsl:copy-of in all of those calls. I did not do that when I tried it initially. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please update your question with the initial problematic  xslt and post an answer with the corrected xslt, so others can benefit